# How to draw string in GDI+ Graphics.DrawString that honors the underline chars when I use ampersand?

Tags: delphi, graphics, gdi+, drawstring, drawtext

I'm using GDI+ to draw a string but it does not act like windows DrawText when it comes to honoring the `&` in front of the a char. It just draws & and not underlines next char. Maybe there is an option to turn it on/off? Please help.

Comment: There are many gdi+ wrappers for Delphi and we don't know which one you use

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is difficult to provide a complete answer when we cannot see the code you are currently using to critique where the problem might lie, or even which implementation of the GDI+ API you are using.

The best I can do is provide you with references to the relevant documentation for the underlying GDI+ API's most likely to be involved.

**First:**  [DrawString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms535991(v=vs.85).aspx), used to actually draw text.

**Second:** The [StringFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms534510(v=vs.85).aspx) object passed to **DrawString** to control aspects of the rendering of the supplied string.

**Finally:** The [HotKeyPrefix](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms534131(v=vs.85).aspx) enumeration used in the **StringFormat** object which indicates how hot key prefixes (ampersands) are to be handled.

In your case you are looking for **HotkeyPrefixShow** behaviour.  (The current behaviour you describe is that for **HotkeyPrefixNone**)

Comment: The StringFormat worked, the problem was I could not see the overloaded method that supports StringFormat from the implementation I used